# How can i disable variables in the top of script but also use them in the rest of the code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public List<string> dialogueLines = new List<string>();
public string npcName;
```

I want to see them in the Inspector since later in the script i assign values to this variables but i don't want that the user will be able to change the values in the Inspector when the game is running. I don't want to hide them in the inspector just to make that the user won't be able to change them.

Comment: Er, the user won't be seeing the inspector in a published build...what's your concern here? Or did you write your own inspector to modify serialized variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your variables to be read only through the Editor. The closes thing to what you are looking for is [`CustomPropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomPropertyDrawer.html) which can be used to make a custom Editor attribute. An [example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/489942/how-to-make-a-readonly-property-in-inspector.html) can be found on Unity forum.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;


public class ReadOnlyAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{

}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute))]
public class ReadOnlyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property,
                                            GUIContent label)
    {
        return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property, label, true);
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position,
                               SerializedProperty property,
                               GUIContent label)
    {
        GUI.enabled = false;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Test:

You can use the `ReadOnly` attribute to make it a read only variable.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [ReadOnly]
    public List<string> dialogueLines;

    [ReadOnly]
    public string npcName;
}
```

It works well. The only problem is the when using List/Array, the **size** can still be changed but the item/element in the List/Array cannot be changed.